# Converter um JSON para OBJETO com Angular

Tags: json, angular

Estou com um problema, preciso transformar um objeto JSON que recebo do meu backend para um objeto.

Estou recebendo esse JSON

```
{"content": [{"id": 1, "nomebd": "teste", "email": "hue@nada.com"}, {"id": 2, "nomebd": "oi", "email": "oi"}, {"id": 3, "nomebd": "joao", "email": "tg"}, {"id": 4, "nomebd": "joao1", "email": "tg1"}, {"id": 5, "nomebd": "kkkkk", "email": "kkk"}, {"id": 6, "nomebd": "dae", "email": "dae"}, {"id": 7, "nomebd": "coe", "email": "coe"}, {"id": 8, "nomebd": "dadadad", "email": "dadadadada"}]}
```

ao utilizar o seguinte código

```
this.service.getConfig()
.subscribe(dados => this.cursos = dados)
```

o getConfig() vem do meu serviço que é

```
  getConfig() {
    return this.http.get<Curso[]>(this.url)
  }
```

Gostaria de saber como faço pra transformar esse json em um objeto pra ler com *ngFOR no ANGULAR

Comment: Ele já vem convertido. Tenta fazer assim: `this.service.getConfig().subscribe(dados => this.cursos = dados.content)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se esse JSON que voce recebe esta em formato String voce tem quem fazer um perse JSON.

```
this.service.getConfig()
.subscribe(dados => this.cursos = JSON.parse(dados))
```

pelo que vi no formato de JSON voce vai ter que colocar o *ngFor="curso of cursos.content"

porque o content é o array a ser iterado, o ngFor itera sobre arrays.

ou então você pega so o array

```
this.service.getConfig()
.subscribe(dados => this.cursos = dados.content)
```

dai o ng for fica "curso of cursos"

Comment: não funcionou não, brother, nenhum dos 2 exemplos :(

Comment: Argument of type 'Curso[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. quando tento dar o parse

    .subscribe(dados => this.cursos = JSON.parse(dados))

Comment: você tentou esse: this.service.getConfig().subscribe(dados => this.cursos = dados.content) e depois iterar o for direto no cursos? pode tentar assim também: this.service.getConfig()
.subscribe(dados => this.cursos = JSON.parse(dados).content)

Comment: Resolvido, coloquei; dados = this.cursos = dados ["content"]

Answer (score 0):

Como você pode ver nas saídas no console o tipo destes dados é um **objeto**, que você pode saber facilmente utilizando o operador [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof).

```js
let dados = {"content": [
    {"id": 1, "nomebd": "teste", "email": "hue@nada.com"},
    {"id": 2, "nomebd": "oi", "email": "oi"},
    {"id": 3, "nomebd": "joao", "email": "tg"},
    {"id": 4, "nomebd": "joao1", "email": "tg1"},
    {"id": 5, "nomebd": "kkkkk", "email": "kkk"},
    {"id": 6, "nomebd": "dae", "email": "dae"},
    {"id": 7, "nomebd": "coe", "email": "coe"},
    {"id": 8, "nomebd": "dadadad", "email": "dadadadada"}
]}

console.log(typeof dados);
console.log(dados.content);
```

Agora quanto ao ***ngFor** você pode atribuir o retorno em uma variável e iterar seus valores todos:

```
dadosAPI;

this.service.getConfig()
.subscribe(dados => this.dadosAPI = dados.content)   // itera no objeto todo

=======================

this.service.getConfig()
.subscribe(dados => this.dadosAPI = dados.content.id)   // itera só nos ids
```

**HTML**

```
<ul *ngFor="let dados of dadosAPI">
  <li>{{ dados.id }}</li>
  <li>{{ dados.nomebd }}</li>
  <li>{{ dados.email }}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: ele não acha o ".content"

Comment: Estranho, pode ver aqui como funciona: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-meqiha